# Task Manager: CPU usage history

Tags: performance, cpu, intel, taskmanager

I bougth recently a server with 2 x X5550, they are quad (4 cores each) total 8 cores

If I check the task manager it shows in the CPU usage history 16 diagrams, 
Should't it be 8 cause I have 2 processors with quad?

or the diagrams maybee shows the Threads of the CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPUs have support for HyperThreading, so each core x2 logical CPUs.

You can always lookup the chip specs [on Intel's site](http://processorfinder.intel.com/)

Comment: okej, cause I have also a server with 2 x E5440 processors which is also quad and on the taskmanager it shows only 8 diagrams, 
dosen't E5440 have support for hyper threading

Comment: Not all chips have support for HyperThreading, also HyperThreading can be disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: so there is nothing wrong with the 2 x E5440 showing 8 diagrams,, cause I thougth that the E5440 should also show 16 diragrams like X5550

Comment: That's correct, Intel's site shows no HT for E5440, and HT support for x5550